"{" cannot be followed by "[ " when using pure function
It may be a basic question, but if I use my pure function like the 4th line below, I got a syntax error. Could I know what I did wrong?
    Subscript[\[Epsilon], i_, j_, K_] := Signature[{i, j, k}]
{Subscript[\[Epsilon], 1, 2, 3], Subscript[\[Epsilon], 3, 2, 1] \
}(*{1,-1}*)
Subscript[\[Epsilon], #1, #2, #3] & [1, 2, 3]  (*1*)
Subscript[\[Epsilon], #1, #2, #3] & /@ {[1, 2, 3]}    (*syntex error*)



See “The Four Kinds of Bracketing”

You cannot write [1, 2, 3] by itself, it has no meaning, and it's a syntax error.
The equivalent formulation of your third line is Function[...][1,2,3], so [1,2,3] means the application of function to three arguments.
In the last line, you wrap [1,2,3] in a list, which has no meaning. You probably want to use Apply instead of Map:
Subscript[ϵ, #1, #2, #3] & @@ {1, 2, 3}
(* Subscript[ϵ, 1, 2, 3] *)


@Domain Thank you for your answer. I should use List[] or {}, like (1,2.3}, not [1,2,3] alone.I can also Map with Apply like this:Apply[Subscript[[Epsilon], #1, #2, #3] &  ,#]& /@{{1,2,3},{3,2,1}} to get {1,-1}Thank you again
